# Missing right parenthesis in decode statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

can I know is there any thing wrong with the decode statement as what I would like to do is:

```
    if ((((PRESENT + (LATE/3))/PRESENT + LATE + ABSENT) * (100)) > 80)
    {
       exam_entry = 'YES';
    }
    else
    {
       exam_entry = 'NO'
    }
```

my decode statement is:

```
    DECODE (TRUE, 
              (
               (
                (PRESENT + (LATE/3))/PRESENT + LATE + ABSENT
               )*(100)
              ) >80, 
                'YES', 
                 'NO')   AS  exam_entry
```

Comment: for condition like `>` or `<` you better use `case` statement ..

Comment: thanks, why sir, why not decode?

Comment: You don't need the first argument (TRUE)

Comment: @Programmer DECODE is specific to Oracle whereas CASE works with all DBMSs implementing SQL 92

Comment: thanks, now got it, but still was not working, even i remove the true

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: now working sir, thanks for all your help and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specified condition you can use `case` `when` `then` clause -

```
CASE 
WHEN ((((PRESENT + (LATE/3))/PRESENT + LATE + ABSENT) * (100)) > 80)
    then
      'YES';
    else
      'NO'
 END as exam_entry
```

If you have to use decode you can use like below -

```
decode(sign(80 - (((PRESENT + (LATE / 3)) / PRESENT + LATE + ABSENT) *
               (100))),
          -1,
          'YES',
          'NO') AS exam_entry
```

Comment: thanks sir, sir, can i know like if we have two if statement then only execute, in sql is there any possibilities

Comment: these both way you can use in sql (decode works specifically for Oracle SQL) also .. in case of multiple condition you can use `case` with multiple condition and/or nested `decode` where inner decode will hold your second condition ..